# Is it possible to run jQuery on server side?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am working on web page scraping has AJAX pagination's implemented, Since website is developed in asp i.e. page with extension .aspx I have tried submitting pagination forms to get data from other pages than first page but did not get any success, take a look here code I have used [Scraping data from all asp.net pages with AJAX pagination implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768302/scraping-data-from-all-asp-net-pages-with-ajax-pagination-implemented), So my question is how can I click on pagination links from php i.e. is it possible to run jQuery or javascript on server side?

I know Node.js can be used to run javascript on server side, but don't know how to use it with Apache and PHP

Comment: no but Node.js can(the quick answer!!)

Comment: jQuery code can be upload on server but its effect shown in client side..because its client side programming lang...u can use node.js because its server side javascript

Comment: on .aspx page when I click on pagination links it submits a form via AJAX please check CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS in curl request in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768302/scraping-data-from-all-asp-net-pages-with-ajax-pagination-implemented

Comment: Even if you could use javascript on serverside. you wouldnt be able to scrape the page, cause the dynamic content wouldnt be available, after being modified with javascript. I used to scrape pages myself with curl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript can, in fact, be run on the server side.

[node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

Your solution here, though, would be to use AJAX to call a PHP script for pagination, as server side javascript doesn't make much sense for the issue.

Comment: Not the direction I would advise for simple pagination request?

Comment: how can I use node.js with PHP any examples?

Answer (score 5):

Use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for interacting with HTML pages on other services. There are libraries for PHP like [this](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs).

[CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) is a library built on top of PhantomJS that allows to automate some common testing / scripting tasks.

If you don't need to interact with remote pages but want to extract data from HTML using jQuery selectors, use [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to run jQuery on the serverside, as jQuery runs in the users web browser (inside the javascript interpreter) . You can make an Ajax call via jQuery to a PHP script which can run code on the server.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $('ul li a').on('click',function()
        {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            $.ajax(
            {
                url         : href,
                data        : passData,
                dataType    : 'html'
                beforeSend  : function()
                {

                },
                success     : function(response)
                {
                    //display it as needed...
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<ul>
    <li><a href="paging.aspx?page=1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="paging.aspx?page=2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="paging.aspx?page=3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="paging.aspx?page=4">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

In example above I have four pagination link and on that links click event I make AJAX call and then in AJAX success call back display result as your wish.

**But remember jQuery can't work on server use Node.js.**

Comment: page does not have such simple pagination as page=1 page=2 etc. rather on each click of pagination link it submits a hidden form with fields __EVENTTARGET ,__EVENTARGUMENT ,__VIEWSTATE ,__EVENTVALIDATION etc. I dont know how asp manages pagination.

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe it doesn't matter and i clearly said example...so i just gave you help regarding what you can possibly do...

Answer (score 0):

JQuery and Javascript is a client side language and for the pagination this can be easily achieved using jQuery as it should be.

Ajax can be used to communicate with the server without page rendering and can give the user a better "Client side" experience. You can use Ajax to connect to the server and use jQuery to perform actions the return from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think with ajax you can easily do the pagination thing .  Else if you really wanne go for server side js . Then try [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this, and it was painful.

My recommendation (in the year 2020), especially if you're using React, is to use this: https://cheerio.js.org/.