# Using jQuery as a HTML editor

Tags: jquery

I'm willing to use jQuery API to edit HTMl.
E.g. instead of manually inserting

tags in more than 30 identical spots within html code I want to use jQuery after() method. (actually, it might be pure JS)

It feels like a special environment must be created for this goal? However I don't know what exactly to do.

P.S. I'm on Mac.

Comment: We're more than happy to help but can you please provide an example of what tags you want where in your HTML markup?  And provide an example of what you've tried so far utilizing jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` to the `head` element in your HTML.

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then you can use jQuery in any `<script>` tag.
Read this page: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp for more info.

---

For jQuery's `after` function:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").after("<p>Hello world!</p>");
});
```

This code inserts a `p` paragraph tag after each `p` element in your HTML.

For more on the `after` function, read here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_after.asp

Comment: I know how to use jQuery for general purposes. Please, pay attention at my question more closely. I meant using jQuery functions for HTML code editing. I don't jQuery to be executed on client side.

Comment: If you don't want jQuery on client side, then use node.js, related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109465/is-it-possible-to-run-jquery-on-server-side. Or, you could use ASP.net with codebehind.