# Add JQuery in NodeJS using existing min file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

Is it possible to add JQuery in Node.js and do JQuery AJAX calls (without changing syntax) using an existing minimized JQuery file I downloaded? In other words, I have the min file and I want to use it in Node.js like this

```
var jquery = require('../public/jquery.min.js');
```

This currently returns **ReferenceError: $ is not defined** error when the AJAX call runs.

Comment: Any reason you can't just install appropriate npm packages and use those? There is [request](https://github.com/request/request) for HTTP requests, and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) for HTML parsing. Node also has a built-in [HTTP module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it that way.  `require` expects a node module, which has an `exports` statement in it.  You'll need to either use the npm module or put your existing file in a `script` tag.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by putting existing file in script tag. Which file are you talking about?

Comment: Also is it possible to go inside that min file and export it?

Comment: `<script src="/path/to/your/script"></script>`  Just a normal script tag.  You should not be mucking around with the jquery.min file.  This explains all of your options: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

Comment: @jmargolistvt how can I just add a script tag in node.js server side. Isn't that browser only

Comment: Not sure why you'd want jQuery on the server side, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109465/is-it-possible-to-run-jquery-on-server-side  If you want it for the front end, just add the tag to your index.html or whatever your home/root page is.

Comment: Serverside because I want to do AJAX on server side, looks like node module is my only option

Comment: That's true, then.  But if that's your use case, don't bother with jQuery at all.  Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157835/discussion-between-jmargolisvt-and-kevin-b).